# ¿countably natural models?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, model-theory

¿ A set theory can have countably models models that can it be natural models, where ∈ relation in the internal model , it is, can be the real ∈ in the external model?

Comment: It is entirely unclear what you are asking. If you are better with a language other than English, you may want to write your post in that language and ask a user here to translate it.

Comment: The close votes are perfectly reasonable, given that the question is unclear; I think the downvotes are unnecessary though. I believe the problem is one of language, not inherent quality of question; and if I've interpreted the question correctly, it's actually quite reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the question you're asking is: "If $V$ is some uncountable background model of set theory, can we have a countable $M\subseteq V$ such that the substructure $(M, \in)$ is a model of set theory?" That is, can we find countable models of set theory with the "right" notion of "element of"?

If this is what you're asking, then the answer is "yes" (assuming there are models of set theory at all): the Lowenheim-Skolem theorem gives us such submodels (which are *elementary submodels* as well as just being models of set theory). Moreover, we can even have such models which are *transitive* - $x\in M, y\in x\implies y\in M$ (though in this case we have to give up elementarity - e.g., such an $M$ will never compute $\mathbb{R}$ correctly).

Does this answer your question? (If there are language issues, you might want to write your question in your native language, and then someone can translate it accurately for you.)

Comment: Are you sure? As I understand it downward Lowenheim-Skolem gives you a model, but not necessarily a standard model. It seems that attempting to build a minimal standard submodel gives you $L$ instead, which is obviously not countable.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro That's not true. Lowenheim-Skolem gives you a countable elementary submodel of any starting model. Since it's a substructure, the "$\in$"-relation is exactly the same.

Comment: I stand corrected. I would think such an object would be better studied, though, since it would seem that you could find a minimal submodel with some good uniqueness properties. For instance, what is the height of the ordinals in this transitive standard countable model?

Comment: @MarioCarneiro Quite right, it is interesting! See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_model_(set_theory) for starters. As far as I know, there isn't a snappier description for that ordinal than "the least ordinal not contained in every countable transitive model of set theory," and in fact you can prove it can't have a 'nice' description in the following way: if I have a nice description of it, then ZFC can prove that there is such an ordinal, so an ordinal satisfying that description must live in my model; but if the description is really nice it should be absolute, contradiction. (cont'd)

Comment: This style of argument shows e.g. that this $\alpha$ must be bigger than $\omega_1^{CK}$, the least noncomputable ordinal. And so forth.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the link, I was looking for something like that. I think my initial confusion came from this: "Of course, any consistent theory must have a model, so even within the minimal model of set theory there are sets which are models of ZF (assuming ZF is consistent). However, those set models are non-standard. In particular, they do not use the normal element relation and they are not well founded." The construction process which produces a countable standard model requires there to already exist a *standard* model, and the minimal model does not contain any standard models.

Comment: But that leaves open the question of how you managed to find a standard model in $V$ to begin with. You start by assuming that "there are models of set theory at all", but in order to apply L-S you need a standard model, not just any model. So for instance assuming ZFC is consistent is not enough to get a standard model, but assuming an inaccessible cardinal is.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro There's a subtle issue here. In order to even talk about a "standard model," we need a background universe to evaluate what "standard" means. Now, the OP was talking about *relatively standard* submodels, that is, a situation where we have $M\subset N$ countable, $N$ an uncountable model of ZFC. Given any uncountable model $N$ of ZFC at all, LS *does* give us a countable, relatively standard submodel $M$. This application of LS, though, happens *externally* - that is, it takes place in an even bigger model $V$, in which $N$ exists as a set. (cont'd)

Comment: So we may quite easily have an uncountable model $N$ of set theory, which thinks "there are no standard models of ZFC," but there will be a sub*set* $M$ of $N$ which does form a relatively standard submodel - it's just we won't have $M\in N$. So LS is enough (again, assuming that there is an uncountable set model of ZFC at all, to make the question non-vacuous). (cont'd)

Comment: Tl;dr, the statement "if $(N, \in^N)$ is an uncountable model of ZFC, then there is a countable $M\subseteq N$ such that $(M, \in^N\upharpoonright M)\models ZFC$)" is true, provably in in ZFC (in fact, much *much* less) just by using LS.